# dotnet build fails on Jenkins pipeline but successful thru freestyle job

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm trying to build a `dotnet` core app using "`dotnet build`".
I have got the same code, tools and Jenkins nodes(windows) but the build fails with below error when executed using a pipeline. But the build ends successful when ran on multiple local computers, freestyle job on same Jenkins nodes.
ERROR:

```
D:\tools\dotnet-v2.1.3\sdk\2.1.302\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4172,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\xyz.zyz.ABC.dll" because it was not found. [JENKINS_WORKSPACE\pipeline\Service\Source\service_client\ABC.csproj]
```

Not sure what's happening. I'm able to build for other `.Net` core apps with the same pipeline scripts on same environments.

Thanks in Advance,
Partha

Comment: welcome to S.O Partha. Could you share us your configuration ?

Comment: Thanks Richard. I'm using .Net core 2.1.302 for build actions. Could you please let me know what configurations you are specifically requesting?

Comment: If you are using a pipeline, maybe your script could help us to understand your problem.